# MySQL reports a primary key but can not drop it from the table

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of updating some tables in my database and I use the following code to check for a primary key and drop it then add a new primary key.

```
if(strpos($value,'PRIMARY') !== false)
{
    $dropit = "DROP PRIMARY KEY ,";
    $query = "ALTER TABLE `".$tablename."` ".$dropit." ADD PRIMARY KEY (`".$name."`);" ;
}
```

When I run I get this error:

> 1091 - Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists SQL=ALTER
>   TABLE `my_table` DROP PRIMARY KEY , ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

After some googling I have seen this issue show up on the MySQL bug reports form like 2006 so I would have figured it would be resolved by now. [MySQL Bugs](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=26076) My version of My SQL is 5.1.44 so not super old... It seems that a column can look like a primary key but not be a primary key... so I am wondering if there is a better way to check before I try and remove to prevent the error.

I have also seen this on some Drupal forums but no clues are given on how to resolve...

If you think more of the surrounding code will help let me know and I will add.

Comment: We need more context: what holds `$value` variable?. Why are you dropping and creating a PK?

Comment: It's obviously not reading the entire value of 'primary key'. What if you truncate the query to simply drop the pk without reading the new one. Does it work then?

Comment: Removing the "ADD PRIMARY KEY ('".$name."')" does nothing the error still occurs.

Comment: the $value var contains something like this: PRIMARY KEY (`table_item_id`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trying to drop the key that's named PRIMARY. Although I'm not sure why it's not working (as the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) clearly show `DROP PRIMARY KEY`), you can try to change your SQL to something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` DROP KEY `key_name`, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: It looks like: [drop key \`PRIMARY\`] also works.  Primary keys seem to get auto-renamed to "PRIMARY"...

Comment: for some reason this worked... I am starting to wonder if it is just my development environment (XAMPP on a MAC)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "add primary key" and have that as an additional sql call.

Answer (score 1):

Try flipping the order:

```
query = "ALTER TABLE `".$tablename."` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`".$name."`), DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

The SQL looks like this, and is capable of changing the primary key of a table in one statement:

```
alter table `sometable` add primary key(`newcolumn`),  drop PRIMARY key;
```

Splitting it into 2 statements also works, but then you may lose some atomicity depending on your environment.

Looks like this also works, and isn't relying on strangeness in behavior to work correctly:

```
alter table sometable drop key `PRIMARY`, add primary key(`somecolumn`);
```

Comment: The problem is that I always have to drop the key if it is already there... if I add it first I accomplish nothing...

Comment: Actually, if you flip the order, they both execute in the same statement, except the statement actually works...  Both operations occur, I was able to change the primary key of a table using this SQL.

Comment: I understand that this works but aren't you just dropping the PRIMARY KEY you just added?  I need to drop the PRIMARY KEY that supposedly exists and replace it with a new PRIMARY KEY... your code seems to be self defeating... but I am not a MySQL expert so maybe it works IDK

Comment: No, since it is one statement it's up to MySQL to decide what order things happen in.  In this case, the add and drop both happen.  Note: See edit, there's a simpler, less hackish way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This frustrated me to no end.  When I ran:

`mysql> describe my_table;`

I got:

```
+-------------+------------+-----+
| Field       | Type       | Key |
+-------------+------------+-----+
| FIELD_ONE   | datetime   |     |
| FIELD_TWO   | char(6)    | PRI |
| FIELD_THREE | int        | PRI |
+-------------+------------+-----+
```

But when I ran `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP PRIMARY KEY`, I received the `Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists` error.

So instead, I ran:

`mysql> SHOW INDEX FROM my_table;`

And in the `Key_name` column there was an old key (using table columns that didn't even exist anymore!?).  So I then ran:

`mysql> ALTER TABLE my_table DROP old_key_that_does_not_exist;`

...and it worked!  I re-ran `DESCRIBE my_table` and got:

```
+-------------+------------+-----+
| Field       | Type       | Key |
+-------------+------------+-----+
| FIELD_ONE   | datetime   |     |
| FIELD_TWO   | char(6)    |     |
| FIELD_THREE | int        |     |
+-------------+------------+-----+
```

*Running InnoDB version 5.7.23.*